# Encrypt data with public key in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, public-key-encryption

I am working on an integration with an API that requires the creation of such a token:

Base64(encrypt(public_key, (token + '|' + challenge.getTime).getBytes))

I'm loading the public key in the script, the token is fixed, and the challenge is a fixed timestamp returned by the API and converted to ISO. The problem is that the API returns an error about the content not being encrypted correctly. When I display the contents of the $encrypted_data variable I see that after each page refresh this value is different. Should this be the case? I have been stuck for many hours and have run out of options and ideas.

```
$fopen_public = fopen("publicKey.pem","r");
$public_key = fread($fopen_public,8192);
fclose($fopen_public);

$pkey_public = openssl_pkey_get_public($public_key);

$token = 'contents of the token';

$challenge = "2022-12-22T08:51:41.166Z"; 

$timestamp = strtotime($challenge);

$data = $token . '|' . $timestamp;

$encrypted_data = '';

$public_key = openssl_csr_get_public_key($public_key); 
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted_data, $pkey_public);
$encrypted_data = base64_encode($encrypted_data);

echo $data."<br>".$timestamp."<br>".$encrypted_data."<br><br>$challenge<br>$timestamp";
```